# How can I make a hand made lock file in ksh?

Tags: file, locking, ksh

I want to create a hand made lock file in order to have a process running n times at same time trying to edit a file, but they have to wait for its turn.

I tried something like this, but I it's working...
    any suggestions?

```
function (){
if test -f file.lock
 then
 print lock file exist
 sleep 5
 else
 print lock > file.lock
fi
}

function
stuff of the code
 rm file.lock
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Can you extend your question to include step-by-step use case of what you are trying to achieve. You say "... but I it's working ...", do you mean "not working"? Good luck.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/045](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045) and [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 0):

Strange method. Chances are the usual bash method works with ksh, too:

```
exec 9>>lockfile
flock 9
```

[Preventing lock propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866175/locking-in-bash-again-how-to-prevent-lock-propagation)